# Getting two different responses in Nuxt 3, fetching external API

Tags: fetch-api, jira-rest-api, nuxtjs3, request-headers

i want to create a request on my jira test instance using Nuxt 3. On my .vue file there should be the  tag. into this tag i will use the provided function useAsyncData from Nuxt 3.

As I interpret the jira docs for fetching the Rest API correctly, then i had to pass the authentication header directly with my fetch, for authentication and getting the right result.

Now my problem is, that i will have to different responses. In my Browser i will get the correct amount of projects into my jira (i was logged into my jira account) but my nuxt application get empty projects with the same request url.

Maybe you could help me, to understand my problem. I've only post my  code here:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

const config = useRuntimeConfig()
const authHeader = `Basic ${btoa(`${config.public.jiraUser}:${config.public.jiraKey}`)}`;

// Fetching Data and getting response
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${config.public.jiraUrl}/project/search`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': authHeader,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)
  }

  const data = await response.json()
  return data
}

const { data: projects, error } = useAsyncData('projects', fetchData)

watchEffect(() => {
  if (error.value) {
    console.error(error.value)
  }
  if (projects.value) {
    console.log(projects.value)
  }
})
</script>
```